# What is the purpose of もの in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

In the sentence

> user3856370は鬼のおなかの中を、針の刀でちくちくと刺したものだから、鬼はたいへんです。

What is the purpose of ものだ? It seems to me that ...刺したから... (because he stabbed) would work on its own. I could also imagine that ...刺したのだから... might work where the のだ is the explanatory-の thing. But I can't make sense out of the whole ...刺したものだから... construction.

PS. I didn't really stab the ogre but I couldn't find the right kanji for the correct name.

Comment: 「一寸法師」ちゃう？-----

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In meaning, 「ものだから」＝「ので」 and the two are interchangeable.  Both express a reason or cause.

I would recommend that you learn 「ものだから」 as a unit, but if you have to parse it, it is like this:

「もの」 is a dummy noun.　It is needed to connect 「[刺]{さ}した」 and 「だ」grammatically.

「だ」 is an affirmation auxiliary verb.

「から」 is a conjunctive particle.

Thus, 「[刺]{さ}したものだから」 means the exact same as 「刺したので」 -- "because (someone) stabbed".

Needless to say, 「も**の**だから」 is often pronounced as 「も**ん**だから」 in colloquial speech.  Additionally, one might also need to know that 「ものだから」 is already fairly informal to begin with.  It is definitely more informal than 「ので」.